# Python Numba Polynomial Root Lower Error with Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, numba

I have created a function which, given ranges of coefficients, constructs polynomials with such coefficients and outputs a list of all their roots. However, Numba doesn't like it. It's like this:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import itertools
from numba import jit
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import Poly

@jit
def polyn(ranges=[[-20,20],[-20,20],[-20,20],[-20,20]],step=4):
    l = []
    x = Symbol('x')
    rangl = [np.linspace(i[0],i[1],math.floor((i[1]-i[0])/step)) for i in ranges]
    coeffl = iter(itertools.product(*rangl))
    leng = 1
    for i in rangl:
        leng *= len(i)
    for i in range(0, leng):
        a = solve(Poly(list(next(coeffl)),x),x)
        for j in a:
            l.append(j)
    return np.array(l)
```

When I try to run this, it outputs a cryptic:
    AssertionError: Failed at object (object mode frontend)
which I do not understand... Can anyone help?

Comment: Numba isn't going to be able to speed up the SymPy code. If that is a bottleneck, you could try using a numeric solver. Another thing to try is to solve a general cubic (with symbolic coefficients), and plug in the values the the general solutions.

Comment: No, I know - but would it not speed up the iteration of such an operation over a large array? (sympy solving)

Comment: I'm doubtful if it would, except maybe if you used it to run in parallel with the nogil options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things in your code which Numba can't cope with currently.  The first is the list comprehension where you build `rangl`:

```
[np.linspace(i[0],i[1],math.floor((i[1]-i[0])/step)) for i in ranges]
```

You should replace this with a NumPy solution like:

```
rangl = np.empty((len(ranges), step))
for i in ranges:
    rangl[i] = np.linspace(i[0],i[1],math.floor((i[1]-i[0])/step))
```

The second thing Numba can't cope with is itertools.product.  You can replace that with NumPy and a for loop as well.

In general, try to reduce your code by commenting out the lower part of it until you get Numba to accept it, then work from the top down and see which parts it can't compile.  Be methodical, go step by step, and try to stick to simple constructs like simple `for` loops and arrays.

Comment: Thanks! How would you suggest replacing the itertools.product for an arbitrary number of arrays?

Comment: @IskyMathews: Make it work for a fixed number, then generalize.   You can take inspiration (maybe even some of the code) from the itertools implementation.